# Can we show two sections with fixed height CollectionView in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, sections

I have given collectionview constraints like below

```
top = leading = trailing = 10, height = 130
```

collectionview cell code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4.1
    
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 100)
    self.filesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

**code for sections and rows**: with this code both array images are showing in one horizontal line

how to show `oldArray` images in one section and `newArray` images in another section

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    
    if isEdit{
        return oldArray.isEmpty ? 1 : 2
    }
    else{
        return 1
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if isEdit{
        if section == 0{
            return  newArray.count
        }
        else{
            return  self.oldArray.count
        }
    }
    else{
        return  self.newArray.count
    }
    return 0
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like either `isEdit` is `true`, or the arrays have been mixed together somewhere.